# Reload current page in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have an [Aurelia](http://www.aurelia.io) application where the user can select the company they're currently "working on". Every page in the app is dependent on the currently selected company, and the user can select a new company from a drop-down menu. The drop-down is a component sitting on the nav-bar.

What I'd like is to have that component reload the current page on the `change.delegate` handler without restarting the app. So setting `window.location.href` is out of the question.

**Is there a way to force the aurelia `Router` to reload the current route/page?**

The alternative would be to use the `EventAggregator` to signal a company change throughout the app, but that would require either subscribing to that event on every page or having every page inherit from a base class that subscribes to that event, but these are much more involved options.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This does not answer your exact question which is *how to force a reload of the current view*, but have you considered adding the current company identifier to your route(s)? This will solve your problem and make your routes bookmarkable: ie: `/#/company1/view1` and `/#/company2/view1`. When you change the company in the drop-down you call `router.navigate()` with the new route and the new view will be loaded/refreshed.

To answer your exact question, I tested the `router.navigate` options: `router.navigate('myroute', {replace:true, trigger:true})` and none of them force a reload of the view if the right view is already loaded. By appending `?ramdomNumber` to your route name you can force a reactivation of the view.

Comment: I had actually tried appending the name of the company to the routes (`/dashboard/company1`) instead of using a random number, but that didn't work... And now I realize that it's because I needed to define the route `"dashboard/:company"` :/

Comment: That would have worked with `?` as in `/dashboard?company1` not `/`.

Answer (score 15):

While not officially supported, there are a variety of <strike>hacks</strike> suggestions [in a relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/201) asking for this very functionality.

The one I got to work that does not involve updating aurelia's source code nor adding superfluous data to the route is to set the [`activationStrategy`](https://aurelia.io/docs/api/router/interface/RouteConfig/property/activationStrategy/) on all of my routes to be `invokeLifecycle` instead of the default, like so:

```js
import { activationStrategy } from 'aurelia-router';

export class App {

  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.map([
      { 
        route: ['', 'home'],
        name: 'home',
        moduleId: 'home/index',
        activationStrategy: activationStrategy.invokeLifecycle
      },
      {
        route: 'users',
        name: 'users',
        moduleId: 'users/index',
        nav: true,
        activationStrategy: activationStrategy.invokeLifecycle
      },
      ... etc ...
    ]);
  }

}
```

This makes it so the route's `activate()` method will run as you expect when the view model is reloaded. Then, in the code that initiates the reload, I do the following:

```js
this.router.navigateToRoute(
  this.router.currentInstruction.config.name,
  this.router.currentInstruction.params,
  { replace: true }
);
```

Comment: Interesting... I'll give it a go!

Comment: You're my hero, this is perfect!

Comment: Best answer thanks! would have saved me just a few mins if you would have let me know i can `import {activationStrategy} from 'aurelia-router'`

Comment: Works really well but I had to replace `this.router.currentInstruction.params` with `this.router.currentInstruction.queryParams`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution to refresh the page:
in *aurelia-history-browser.js*, added a check in `updateHash()` and if the new _href is equal to the old then reload the page from the cache (not the server).

Then, to refresh the page you just need to use the existing options:

```
router.navigateToRoute('watch', {}, { replace: true, trigger: true });
```

The updated code is copied below:

```
function updateHash(location, fragment, replace) {
    if (replace) {
      var _href = location.href.replace(/(javascript:|#).*$/, '') + '#' + fragment;
      if (_href == location.href)
        location.reload(false);
      else
        location.replace(_href);
    } else {
      location.hash = '#' + fragment;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Better answer:

```
this.router.navigateToRoute(
  this.router.currentInstruction.config.name,
  {
    ...this.router.currentInstruction.params,
    reload: Number(this.router.currentInstruction.queryParams.reload || 0) + 1,
  },
  { trigger: true },
);
```

The `navigateToRoute()` takes 3 parameters:

1. **Name of route:** (get from current instruction)
2. **Route parameters:** (get from current instruction and add an incremental reload to change the route; easiest way to make the router actually navigate)
3. **Options:**  The `trigger: true` option forces an `activationStrategy: invokeLifecycle` on this specific routing instruction without the need to set this option in the viewModel or routeConfig for normal routing.

Comment: This looks like the most elegant solution, but I'm not having luck getting it to work. The "reload" query parameter appends to the URL properly, but the "trigger" never seems to occur.