# how to route the same page with same url and update content in Aurelia

Tags: routes, navigation, aurelia

Eg: In view agreement List and create agreement in same page. i want to reload the
agreement List after save the new agreement.i try this this.router.navigate('/agreement/client/10') but this is not load the new list because the it's  navigating the same url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reload current page in Aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845637/reload-current-page-in-aurelia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `configureRouter` method, add `activationStrategy.replace` to routes that need this functionality:

```
import {activationStrategy} from 'aurelia-router';

export class MyClass {
    configureRouter(config) {
        config.map([{
            route: 'my-route',
            name: 'my-name',
            activationStrategy: activationStrategy.replace,
            title: 'My Title',
            moduleId: 'myModule',
        }]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. this solution is working fine. when i try to save one agreement this is working. when i change again that agreement this is not working. any solution for this???

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Event Aggregator, and publish an event when you add a new agreement, and reload the list when the event is triggered.